# How to redirect to an ASP.net MVC action for url with hash parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am using ASP.Net core 2.2. I redirect to an identity server instance, which then redirects back to my MVC app. The redirect back url is of the form:

> `http://localhost:8081/home/fetchtokenresponse#id_token=longtokenvalue&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600&scope=myscopes&session_state=jizlw_6DiGhYvkGk6fKRKkhZQoFlYKJ5v1_2Lwd-caI.MN0g0HwpGuulkwKleHtJCg`

In my action I want to be able to read the parameters like

```
public IActionResult FetchTokenResponse(string id_token)
```

**What I have tried**

I tried adding a new route with a has tag, but this appears to be illegal:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}#{id?}");
```

Is there another way to intercept the path and redirect to my action?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The _id_token_ most likely only contains the `sub` claim (by default), and if not (because you may have set `options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true`), these claims are automatically added to the cookie.

Comment: The access_token is in there too, I probably haven't shown this very well. What I have is an application using LDAP authentication, but it needs to call into different clusters for various reasons and needs to authenticate into them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to modify your authentication request to IdentityServer to use `response_mode=form_post` or `response_mode=query`.

Fragments are not sent to the server, as defined in: https://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/03/01/6-things-you-should-know-about-fragment-urls/.
Fragment response mode is used when you want your front-end JavaScript to grab the tokens.