# Can I setup authentication in MVC so that it doesn't need to reauthenticate on postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver4

This is a follow-up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60741767/how-to-redirect-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-for-url-with-hash-parameter?noredirect=1#comment107475852_60741767)

I log in to my app using LDAP authentication. I need to call some APIs in another cluster, so I redirect to the authorize page, and it posts back to me the token information. Unfortunately, this post-back is meaning that my app then asks me to re-enter my LDAP credentials, and I lose the posted back information.

Is there a way that I can prevent this from happening? I would have thought my session was still valid.

```
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;


            });

            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Login";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Error/AccessDenied";

            });
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {

            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = false;
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have ended up doing is posting back to an action that is marked with

```
  [AllowAnonymous]
```

which seems to then not ask me to login again. I am still open to any other better solution suggestions though.